# what is the goal and output of process in Scratch.hs and running example such as BasicSpec.casl got error with Scratch

Tags: haskell, maude-system

**update1**

1. i have to cabal install maude in order to use rewrite, if not import maude, how can het tools's haskell code use rewrite and reduce in its haskell code?
2. how to prove the logic with algebraic spec input file or default system
   and logic string as parameters to return output into console ? is there examples for this and do all these in Scratch?
3. Moreover would like to read Owl file in Scratch and do inference in Scratch, is there example for this?

https://github.com/spechub/Hets/blob/master/Scratch.hs

**update2**
succeed to run first example RelationAndOrders.casl, however, what is the goal and output of process in Scratch.hs

```
martin@ubuntu:~/Downloads/Hets-master$ sudo cp Scratch /usr/lib/hets/hets-lib/Basic/Scratch
martin@ubuntu:~/Downloads/Hets-master$ cd /usr/lib/hets/hets-lib/Basic
martin@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hets/hets-lib/Basic$ ./Scratch RelationsAndOrders.casl 
### file name 'RelationsAndOrders.casl' does not match library name 'Basic/RelationsAndOrders'
Analyzing library Basic/RelationsAndOrders version 1.0
Downloading Basic/Numbers ...
Analyzing library Basic/Numbers version 1.0
Analyzing spec Basic/Numbers?Nat
Analyzing spec Basic/Numbers?Int
Analyzing spec Basic/Numbers?Rat
Analyzing spec Basic/Numbers?DecimalFraction
... loaded Basic/Numbers
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?Relation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?ReflexiveRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?IrreflexiveRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?SymmetricRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?AsymmetricRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?AntisymmetricRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?TransitiveRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?SimilarityRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?PartialEquivalenceRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?EquivalenceRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?PreOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?StrictOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?PartialOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?TotalOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?StrictTotalOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?RightUniqueRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?LeftTotalRelation
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?BooleanAlgebra
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?ExtPartialOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?ExtTotalOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?ExtBooleanAlgebra
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?RichPartialOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?RichTotalOrder
Analyzing spec Basic/RelationsAndOrders?RichBooleanAlgebra
Analyzing view Basic/RelationsAndOrders?TotalOrder_in_Nat
Analyzing view Basic/RelationsAndOrders?TotalOrder_in_Int
Analyzing view Basic/RelationsAndOrders?TotalOrder_in_Rat
Analyzing view Basic/RelationsAndOrders?PartialOrder_in_ExtBooleanAlgebra
```

**update3**

when running  BasicSpec.casl

```
martin@ubuntu:~/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test$ ./Scratch BasicSpec.casl
Analyzing file BasicSpec.casl as library BasicSpec
Analyzing spec BasicSpec?BasicSpec

unexpected mixfix token: 252
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:710.31:
*** Error:
missing %number annotation
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:710.31:
*** Error:
unexpected mixfix token: 253
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:711.31:
*** Error:
missing %number annotation
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:711.31:
*** Error:
unexpected mixfix token: 254
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:712.31:
*** Error:
missing %number annotation
/home/martin/Downloads/Hets-master/CASL/test/BasicSpec.casl:712.31:
*** Error:
unexpected mixfix token: 255
Scratch: user error (Stopped due to errors)
```

Comment: Your ghc version is _ancient._ Have you tried with a fresh one? We're on 7.10 now.

Comment: @Sarah Well... GHC 6.4 was originally released 11 March 2005. So it's one decade old at this point.

Comment: i tried a new ghc , it is ok, just ask for one of my Virtual machine which can only use version 6.4

Comment: @user353573 Run a virtual machine with an OS able to run software from the current decade?

Comment: current is latest version, Could not find module `Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph'

Comment: succeed to compile Scratch.hs, but running example in the directory of hets, got error